# How do I shift all the next array values all back by one if the array before is blank?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have lines in a text file that look like:

```
 108    abcdef.ghijkl.com   abcdef.ghijkl.com       NULL    NULL    NULL    4481104 Share   0   1       [abcdef.ghijkl.com] Failed to get CIFS shares with error code -2147024843.      Non-supported  share access type.   0   Unknown NULL    ntap
```

There's supposed to be a tab in between each value. However, if you scroll to the right, there's two tabs after **4481104 Share   0   1**. There are a bunch of lines that don't have this problem, but a few that do.

How do I shift all the next array values all back by one if the array before is blank (get rid of that extra tab) so it looks like:

```
 108    abcdef.ghijkl.com   abcdef.ghijkl.com       NULL    NULL    NULL    4481104 Share   0   1   [abcdef.ghijkl.com] Failed to get shares with error code -2147024843.       Non-supported  share access type.   0   Unknown NULL    ntap
```

So far I've tried a bunch of things, including:

```
   for line in fp:
        line = line.strip()  # remove the newline
        if line.strip() == '':
            prev[4:] = prev[3:]
```

But that doesn't work (can't reassign strings). Would appreciate any insight, thank you.

*UPDATE*: Array example:

> [108, abcdef.ghijkl.com, abcdef.ghijkl.com, NULL, NULL,   , NULL,
>   4481104, Share, 0, 1, '   ',[abcdef.ghijkl.com] Failed to get CIFS
>   shares with error code -2147024843., Non-supported  share access
>   type., 0, Unknown NULL, ntap]

ALSO  there are two double tab parts, and I only want to get rid of one double tab.

Comment: can you add the array so others can try out code, you can just post the output of `print(array)`, cheers

Comment: ktzr - done! jdehasa - didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Read contents of file into string, replace double tabs with single tabs.
new_content = open('/path/to/file.txt', 'r').read().replace('\t\t', '\t')
# Overwrite original file with new contents.
open('/path/to/file.txt', 'w').write(new_content)
```

Comment: This was helpful! What if in the error lines (shown above) there are two double tab parts, and I only want to get rid of one double tab? Wish I noticed this earlier :(

Comment: @Rachel One method would be to just change the string that's being replaced to include the character(s) before or after the double-tab you want to replace.
Example: 'new_content = open("/path/to/file.txt", "r").read().replace("\t\tNon-supported", "\tNon-supported")'

Comment: I did: line = line.strip().replace("\t\t[", "\t["), based on your wonderful suggestions. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

So you want to replace 2 or more consecutive tabs with 1 single tab ?
Use either a regex like @jdehesa suggested, or something like:

```
with open('yourfile.dirty', 'rt') as finput:
    for line in finput:
        your_array = [token for token in line.strip().split('\t') if token != '']
        # do_something(your_array )
```

You can even write a cleaned file with:

```
with open('yourfile.dirty', 'rt') as finput, \
     open('yourfile.cleaned', 'wt') as foutput:
    for line in finput:
        clean_line = '\t'.join(token for token in line.strip().split('\t') if token != '')
        foutput.write(line)
        foutput.write('\n')
```